# Asp.Net Core Update Enum items dynamically (add item, delete item,etc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, enums

I am trying to build database table (posts) this table contains column(category) and column(sections), i want to assign the value of these two tables (category,section) using Enum values , so when i want to add new category i need to update category enum and add new item inside the enum but dynamically (using user interface),can i do these updates just like this way and how?

this is the enum:

```
 public enum Category
    {
        [Display(Name = "New")]
        New = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Active")]
        Active = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Inactive")]
        Inactive = 2,
        [Display(Name = "Suspended")]
        Suspended = 3,
        [Display(Name = "Suspicious")]
        Suspicious = 4
    };
```

Comment: Enums are the wrong approach here. You cant do anything dynamically with them (or if you can you shouldnt). However you have a database. use that instead

Comment: i know i can build a table for (section) and table for(category), but i just want to see if we can do this way

Comment: If you use enums every time you add a new category, you will need to rebuild and deploy your application. "*but i just want to see if we can do this way*" - The answer is no, not with enums, not like this. You have a database, just use it :)

Comment: yes , you are right , thanks alot

Comment: If your enum wants to be updated frequently, so forget about it. Use a table in your database for your Categories.